# Sequência de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou a receber a "Sequência de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto" quando faço uma inclusão no banco e actualizo a gridview.

Porém isso só acontece para o primeiro registo. 
Pelo que tentei já percebi que o erro vem do código do C# e não da base de dados.

O código em questão:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEfluentes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsCaixasSeparadoras" OnDataBound="gvEfluentes_OnDataBound" SkinID="noSort">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nro_caixa" HeaderText="Caixa Nº" SortExpression="Nro_caixa">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Desc_modelo" HeaderText="Modelo" SortExpression="Desc_modelo">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Outro_modelo" HeaderText="Outro modelo" SortExpression="Outro_modelo">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Desc_eficiencia" HeaderText="Eficiência" SortExpression="Desc_eficiencia">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Desc_recebe" HeaderText="Receber de" SortExpression="Desc_recebe">
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCaixasSeparadoras" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="FEPAM.CADASTROS.DAL.PostosCaixasParametros"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDadosPostoCaixaParametro"
    SortParameterName="SortExpression" TypeName="FEPAM.CADASTROS.BLL.PostoCaixaParametro">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="ptcb_id" SessionField="PTCB_ID" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SortExpression" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Inclua o código que acha que está a causar o problema, a descrição do erro/stack trace e dê uma arrumação na pergunta.

Comment: ja achei a causa do problema  numeroGrid = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)row.FindControl("lkbNumero")).Text); faltou verificar se o textbox era vazio

Comment: ponha a solução numa resposta e marque como respondido para fechar a pergunta.

Comment: onde eu marco como respondida?

Comment: na sua resposta, tem lá um visto que marca como respondida. Só pode marcar a sua própria resposta como certa depois de 48h salvo erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a causa do problema:

```
numeroGrid = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)row.FindControl("lkbNumero")).Text);
```

Faltou verificar se o `textbox` era vazio e numérico.